# Why do I get: "An error occurred submitting the question"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I get the same error whether it's on a Mac mini or PC for this particular content when submitting the question. There is no indication anywhere indicating what problem produces the error. That is, there is no popup nearby explaining the error and how I can fix it. I'm going to paste the question here so you can see if there is something I missed. If I get the error again, I'm going to submit this without the content:

[I get the same error message, so I'm submitting without the content.]

Comment: I notice a floating pale yellow box with How to Format off to the right. Is that a clue? I can't see anything incorrectly formatted.

Comment: If the problem was with the content you would get an error message stating so.  This generally means the site couldn't connect to the server, or the JS code errored out due to some unexpected reason, or some other type of unexpected error.

Comment: @Servy This isn't helpful LOL

Comment: Could you make your question available somewhere else? In a Gist or Pastie perhaps? http://pastie.org/

Comment: Uh, that's completely helpful. Are you blocking scripts at all? Are you in a place where they might be blocking certain sites or CDN's?

Comment: @patricksweeney I'll ask IT now...

Comment: Here's the full question: https://gist.github.com/StevenHu/11380531

Comment: @patricksweeney IT doesn't see any blocks here. [Later:] IT asked me to try again. I deleted the original post and created a new question/answer and now it works.

Comment: From IT: "the site has cross scripting which is a no-no, but I made an exception."

Comment: @Steve "The site has cross scripting which is a no no", does your IT live in a cave or something? Haven't they heard of CDNs? You should encourage your IT to educate themselves on how the internet works and what cross site scripting (XSS) means, and what _actually_ enables it (This is a good page to start https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) )

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I sent him the link.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen under 2 circumstances, both with differing results:

1. The browser's SSL cert store was out of date; the root cert expiration date for the stack* sites had been passed, so anytime I attempted to hit submit the browser was waiting for user intervention to allow it to go through.  However, the warning/error page wasn't actually being displayed so there was just a non-obvious failure.
2. I sometimes see this error because IT uses bluecoat and it sees stack* sites as "forum posts" and has it blocked by default.

Depending on the browser you're using you could pull up its developer tools and investigate what's going on (or a packet capturing tool like wireshark, if you're allowed); for example, in IE:

1. Prepare a submission
2. Press F12
3. Open the network tab
4. Hit record
5. On the original page, hit submit/add comment
6. When all traffic has ceased, hit stop on the recording
7. Sift through the packets and see if you can identify the root cause.

   - In the expired root cert case, a .css request didn't get a response body.  I manually copied the domain into a new tab and received the "invalid cert" warning.
   - In the blocked page case, the response body had the standard bluecoat "this site is blocked" message.

The blocked page case might be worked around using https (if you're not already); for the SSL cert case you should probably have your IT staff look into it, though it can be resolved by downloading the root cert that's giving you issues and installing it.